# Cannot Return Answer From Vector Into An Integer

Tags: c++

```
    int max=0;int answer=0;
    max = max_element(ar.begin(),ar.end());
    answer = find(ar.begin(), ar.end(), max);
    return answer;
```

So what I need is to look through a vector and pick out its biggest value and return how many of the biggest values there are in the vector. Ive tried to use these functions before, seems like it should work but it doesn't.

Error:
cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >’ to ‘int’ in assignment

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: What does `find` return? Is it an `int`? If so, does that correspond to "how many" of anything?

Comment: *and return how many of the biggest values there are in the vector* -- Looks like you used the wrong algorithm function.  If you used `std::count` instead of `find`, your code would work as expected.

Comment: Sounds like you may be looking for [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns an iterator type that matches the `begin` and `end` iterators provided, rather than an index, which is what you seem to be expecting. You can get the desired index by doing:

```
auto find_result = find(ar.begin(), ar.end(), max);
answer = distance(ar.begin(), find_result);
```